# Good practice for handling static pages in SpringMVC

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

How to handle dozens of static pages in spring MVC?
Can I handle it by one Controller function or better to have one function for one page?
Or I have to move static pages to resource folder and handle them like resources?

Comment: pages are simple *.html pages. They have not models and any dynamic data, so i afraid it will be a bad practice to handle them by Controller...

Answer (score 1):

> Can I handle it by one Controller function or better to have one function for one page?

--> Well it would be better to write one function for one page. But at controller level, create controllers according to functionality. If your pages are related with login module, add methods in `LoginController` for your static pages. Similarly if your pages comes under signup module, add them in `SignupController`.

Also if pages contain secure info then add controllers otherwise you can allow public access to static pages.